# Disable onClick

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have designed an UI with some 5-6 buttons and 2 galleries. On click of a button a listView is shown partially (does not cover the entire screen) from top right corner. I want to disable the onClick and scrolling of other buttons and galleries when the listView is visible.

That is I want to achieve a scenario similar to that of alertDialog. I don't want to individually disable the onClick of each button as I may need to add or remove buttons later and maintaining the code may become a tedious work. Is there any way to to disable the onClick and scrolling in general.

PS : It would also be helpful if the onClick and scrolling of a layout can be disabled. In that case I can disable the onClick of all layouts other than that of the listView that pops up

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will work on it and let you know. I can't upvote the answer now as I don't have 15 points yet. Will do that as when I gain 15 points

Comment: You have commented on your question instead of answer :) +1 for your question though

Answer (score 1):

use this-

```
button.setEnabled(false);
```

or

```
 button.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that can be done, but as I mentioned in my question I want to generalise the disabling

Comment: call a method.in that u can pass id's and can disable them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use viewgroup like [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)

and can disable the click event of that view group.